# ADSL Modem loses sync every 93 minutes

Tags: networking, sync, adsl

I've been using a ZTE ZXDSL 831 modem behind a WRT310N router for around 5 years. 2 months ago, lightning struck my house which blew the fuse on our circuit breaker. Once we had the power fixed, my modem got bricked. The router was fine (I just needed to change the power adapter) but could not revive the modem. So I had this replaced to the newer model (ZXDSL 831II). Since then, the connection would drop every 93 minutes.

I've had technicians check the physical line twice, and had the modem replaced twice as well, but the connection will drop at the same interval. They say that the line to my house is fine, as well as to the DSLAM so I'm really at a loss as to what is causing the disconnections. As for possible interference, the location of the modem and router has not changed for the past couple of years and no new appliances or cables were placed near them.

The countdown before the connection drops does not reset when I reset the modem. It will always drop after 93 minutes regardless of the modem up-time.

I cannot post images yet, so I placed the modem stats in text below:

```
ADSL Line State

ADSL Mode Setup - Auto Sync-up
Current ADSL Mode - ADSL2 PLUS
ADSL Up Time - 1:33:19 ---> close to the maximum up-time. Disconnects at around 1:33:52
Downstream Rate - 2048
Downstream Rate - 767
Latency Type - Fast

SNR Margin US/DS - 6.0/45.5
Power US/DS - -14.6/16.2
Line Attentuation US/DS - 7.4/7.9

Annex Type Setup - ANNEX A/L

Current Annex State - Annex_A
Line State - Showtime
```

Whenever it disconnects, the Line State will go from DOWN, to ACTIVATION, to SHOWTIME and it will be connected to the Internet shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have ZTE ZXDSL 831CII Modem I have subscription of 2Mbps Downstream Rate and 0.5Mbps Upstream Rate.
I have frequent disconnection in my internet connection after calling the techs at my ISP I get that we have configured it at our and every thing is fine according to us.So,it works for 1-2 days and then again disconnections.My DSL light on the modem stays stable most of the time but the Internet light goes out frequently.

**SOLUTION That Works For Me**
I put the receiver off the hook of my phone base set(Same service provider for Landline and Internet).
It makes my internet work most of the time but occasionally I do get disconnection in DSL but most of the time it gets connected in a few minutes.After contacting my ISP and telling them how my connection works at my side, there representative said that if thats how it works perhaps your line from Cabinet/Pole connection is loose and you are perhaps not getting full power for both devices(I have Copper Line not Fiber) and when you engage your phone the modem gets the required power so it works and when I tell them to correct it it gets corrected for again 1-2 days and then the same cycle goes on.
Though it is a lame excuse,they have novice technical expertise and don't know how to resolve the problem, I'm sure this is a configuration problem at there end/server.

**Another SOLUTION** 
After inspecting modem configurations of other user(they are new user as compared to me) of the same ISP, in ADSL MODE Setup G.DMT is selected offering only Annex A,and after applying these settings to my modem I got less frequent disconnections without unhooking my phone,yet disconnection is there but less frequently.So,perhaps there is syncing and configuration problem at both end.

So, may be the second solution will work for you as well.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. My problem is still there but I have now asked them to repair the lines from the outside. 
 decided to test the connection from the NID (old-style small one with 2 bolts for the wires) directly but the disconnections still occur so it's safe to say that its not from any internal interference. I'll try switching the ADSL mode, and since we have the same problem albeit disconnecting at different intervals, the problem must in the phone lines outside.